# Unable to launch WebStorm-2016.3-RC

Tags: ide, webstorm, development-environment

I completed the installation of WebStorm-2016.3-RC.exe. WebStorm could not start when I run `webstorm.exe`. This was not helpful as there was no error message.

When I run `webstorm.bat`, I got this error message

> "Error: Could not find or load main class # custom WebStorm VM options".

However, I have no problems launching WebStorm 2016.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I got it working but don't know why it works. You may try the same steps but there is no guarantee it will work on your PC.

Go to the folder where webstorm.exe and webstorm64.exe reside. **Instead of running webstorm.exe, run webstorm64.exe.** This works for me except for a minor hiccup. I need to install jdk ver1.8. You also need to modify JAVA_HOME and point to the jdk ver1.8 folder. After doing this, I can launch webstorm without any problem.